# Checking inheritance from a base-class class method?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I'm developing a set of classes that can have a combination of "abilities." An object can either: generate, characterize, or do both.

I want to be able to check what the abilities are of a current object as that might change what I will do with it. My thought is to have a classmethod in the base class that will use `isinstance()` to determine what the object can do. This is not working for me.

Here is some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```py
class BaseTest:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def can_gen(cls):
        return isinstance(cls, GenTest)

    @classmethod
    def can_char(cls):
        return isinstance(cls, CharTest)


class GenTest(BaseTest):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def gen(self, x):
        pass


class CharTest(BaseTest):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def characterize(self, x):
        pass


class MainTest(GenTest, CharTest):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def gen(self, x):
        print(x)

    def characterize(self, x):
        print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test = MainTest()

    x = isinstance(test, GenTest)
    y = isinstance(test, CharTest)
    z = MainTest.can_gen()

    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)
```

Here is the output:

```
True
True
False
```

It's apparent that not using the classmethod works as expected but when trying to use the classmethod, it's returning `False`.

Why is this happening? Also, I can't change the class structure, so those answers would not be helpful in my case.

Comment: Because `isinstance(MainTest, GenTest)` is *false*, which is what `MainTest.can_gen()` is doing. Why did you make it a classmethod? I'm the behavior you want would work with just a regular *instance* method, as demonstrated by `isinstance(test, GenTest)`

Comment: If it has to work with just the class object, not an instance, then you can use `issubclass` instead of `isinstance`